# How can set tab bar at top of my viewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Currently my `tabBarController` is at the bottom of the `viewController`. I want to change that in to Android like `TabView` in my `viewController`.

Comment: Try it https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

Comment: There are lot of questions already asked in the community. So before posting just do your research and post it. You can do with `self.tabbar.frame =CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)`